# Converting audio from .m4a to .wav in python

Tags: python-3.x, pydub

Need help to convert the audio file having .m4a format to .wav in python

I have also tried: https://gist.github.com/arjunsharma97/0ecac61da2937ec52baf61af1aa1b759/revisions

but not succeeded.

Comment: Hello, did you ever solve this problem? I'm trying to make the same conversion